# how to match some elements in associative array in php

Tags: php, arrays, match, element, associative

I have a following array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => flatrate
            [1] =>  flatrate3
            [2] =>  freeshipping
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => flatrate
            [1] =>  flatrate2
            [2] =>  flatrate3
            [3] =>  flatrate4
            [4] =>  freeshipping
        )

)
```

> Now, i need to match some element in this like
>
> if freeshipping in above array . it should echo yes else no.

Please suggest, how can i do this.

Comment: Use [array_search()](http://in2.php.net/array_search)

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 0; count($array); $i++){
    if(in_array($string, $array[$i]) echo true;
}
```

Comment: It always goes in else condition.

Answer (score 0):

you can do simple code like that :

```
 foreach ($array as $key) {
                    foreach ($key as $value) {
                        if($value == "your condition")
                        {
                        echo 'yes';
                        }else{
                            echo 'no';
                        }
                    }   
                }
```

try it.

Comment: It always goes in else condition.

Comment: if you try to check if flatrate is exist you can do some thing like that : if($value == "flatrate") echo "yes"; it should work with you as previous array example

Answer (score 0):

**Create A function**

```
function checkfreeShipping($arrData)
{
   foreach($arrData as $data){

      if(in_array('freeshipping',$data))
      return true;
   }


}
```

**Call defined function to check Shipping -**

```
if(checkfreeShipping($cartArr)){

  echo "free Shipping";
}
else{
  echo "Paid Shipping";
}
```

Comment: it always goes in else condition

Comment: Not way check carefully. print array and check that `freeshipping` is coming or not. :)